# AutoSuggest Dropdown list getting close automatically, when i move mouse over it to select item in window form Combo box

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, combobox

When i enter text in combo box, i am able to get autosuggest(Filtered) dropdown list. But when i try to select item from dropdown, it is getting closed automatically. How can i keep it visible until I can select item from dropdown list

want to select item from autosuggest dropdown list in window form combo box

```
 private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cmbYear.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        this.cmbYear.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: private void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.cmbYear.AutoCompleteMode=AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
            this.cmbYear.AutoCompleteSource=AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        }

Comment: Set the mode and source once, not on every text change...

Comment: Even if we set mode and source at form properties. AutoSuggest dropdown is getting closed automatically